# How can I give multiple vpc access to a classic ec2 instance using security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

We have multiple a VPC's, one for each of our environments (DEV, QA, PROD) and we have a classic EC2 instance that we use to run some utilities or apps for dev/testing (for example an FTP server and dummy customer API server). I would like to allow any of the EC2 instances in each our VPC's network access to certain ports on the Classic without exposing it to the world. Can anyone explain how I might achieve this? I looked at classic link but that only allows one VPC to link to it

Comment: How does the traffic from VPC instances go to internet? through internet gateway or NAT?

Comment: @helloV internet gateway

Comment: So the instances in VPC that want to access Classic have a IP or elastic IP?

Comment: actually a mixture - some have not needed it prior to now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have few instances from VPC to connect to Classic, then it is easy to add a rule in SG of Classic for each instance in VPC. But you want any current/future instance in VPC to access the Classic. Though I haven't tried, some suggestions:

1. Route the traffic from VPC to internet using a NAT and specify the NAT in your Classic SG. But you cannot access the VPC instances directly. It is ideal for instances in private subnet. From your description, the VPC instances are in public subnet and this solution will not work.
2. Use a proxy (like Squid proxy) and route the traffic to Classic instance from VPC through the proxy.

Launch an instance and install a proxy or launch an instance from an AMI which has a squid proxy already installed

Add a rule in the route table of VPC subnets to route the traffic to Classic through the proxy. Other traffic will be routed through the internet gateway

Add the IP of proxy to the SG of Classic